# regex php to shorten url

Tags: php, regex

I have urls like this

url =  http://mysite1.com/some/path/to/file/{width}x{height}/image.jpg

I want to take out {width}x{height} from the urls so that I would have

```
http://mysite1.com/some/path/to/file/image.jpg
```

How can I do that with regex in php
thanks

Comment: how are the urls generated? this may be a mod_rewrite question but i can't tell

Comment: Needs more info. See comment above. And also will the URLs always have that format. Can you add more examples of real URLs? Is regex a real requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex ought to do it:

```
$url = 'http://mysite1.com/some/path/to/file/123x456/image.jpg';
$result = preg_replace('#/[0-9]+x[0-9]+#', '', $url);

echo $result;
```

Comment: `preg_replace('#/[0-9]+x[0-9]+/#', '/', $url);` would probably be a better choice so you don't match something like `http://someurl/23x245.jpg`.

Comment: doesnt work ..tried it. I need to replace {width}x{height}

Comment: the string {width}x{height}. its not number..so [0-9] wont work

Comment: @Autolycus so str_replace() then no regular expression needed.

Comment: yea did this str_replace("/{width}x{height}/", "/", $url); but it leaves an extra /

Comment: tried this too str_replace("/{width}x{height}/", "", url); but same results

Comment: @Autolycus see my answer. and PLEASE try to write better questions in the future

Answer (score 0):

search for

```
^(http.*[//])(.*)[//](.*jpg)$
```

and replace with

```
\1\3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://mysite1.com/some/path/to/file/{width}x{height}/image.jpg';

echo str_replace("/{width}x{height}", "", $url);
```

output:

> http://mysite1.com/some/path/to/file/image.jpg